# Numerator and denominator definition

Tags: fractions

I am studying fractions and how to calculate them and the terms numerator and denominator appear a lot when I read about it, but I do not know the *numerator* and *denominator* definition.

i.e.

$$
\frac{4}{2} + \frac{8}{2} = \frac{4+8}{2} = \frac{12}{2}
$$

Would I like to know your definition?

Comment: Have you tried asking the internet to  _define numerator_?

Comment: @EthanBolker I tried, but the explanations are complicated for me and I could not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fraction $$\frac{p}{q}$$  where $q\ne 0$

$p$ is called [Numerator](https://study.com/academy/lesson/numerator-denominator-definition-lesson.html) and $q$ is called denominator

Comment: $q$ can be less than zero $q<0$ ?

Comment: It can, but this is generally considered an improper fraction (which might matter or not). You can always change the signs of both denominator and numerator to get an equal fraction, equally in its lowest terms

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out more elaborate definition on the matter.

A numerator is **an integer** above the vinculum, also known as the dividend if the fraction is interpreted as division.

A denominator is **a natural number** below the vinculum, also known as the divisor if fraction is interpreted as division.

If $\gcd(p,q)=1$, with the definitions above, then the fraction is irreducible and is in its **canonical form**.